# How to sketch $(x^2-2)^2 + (y^2-2)^2=2$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

> $$\left(x^{2}-2\right)^{2}+\left(y^{2}-2\right)^{2}=2$$

Pretty much as per the title. Was set as a graph sketching exercise. Can see that it will have symmetry around all 4 axes but unclear as to how I would go about sketching this. I guess I could look at key points e.g. $(1,1), (\sqrt{3},1)$ but not sure it's a great method. Any help appreciated

Comment: Make a slope field.

Comment: You are expected to recognize the standard form of an equation of a circle but with the variables squared.  Define $z=x^2, w=y^2$. What is the center? What is the radius? What does that tell you about the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @NinadMunshi sorry please could you explain what you mean by this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, graph $\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-2\right)^{2}=2$.

Then graph $\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y^{2}-2\right)^{2}=2$.

Then graph $\left(x^{2}-2\right)^{2}+\left(y^{2}-2\right)^{2}=2$.

(At each step explain how the graph is transformed.)